# parent with null is not deleting in self referencing table

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have tree type self referencing table. I want to delete all the child records using root element id. So I added the self referencing constraint with cascade delete. It works when parent have some value that referencing the id. But I entered the root element with null, so it's not getting deleted. Any Idea. How can I delete all the child records when we delete the root in tree view.

Create table query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_quiz` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


ALTER TABLE `_quiz`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `_quiz_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `_quiz` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

My table with data

[image]
[image]

Red highlighted is root. when we delete that all child needs to be deleted. But it's not happening!

Is there any other do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first row is already breaking the constraint, as it doesn't have a parent. If a statement is breaking a constraint, the processing is being stopped immediately.

This is why there won't be any deletions, if you try to delete the first one. Even the first row itself won't be deleted.

Avoid the null in a referencing field. You could set it to reference to itself. I don't know if it could cause any other issues, but it would solve this one. ;)

Comment: Thank you I created default root element to solve this problem